# How long can I run a joist without supporting it in the middle?

Tags: floor, joists, treehouse

I am building a tree house with a bridge from one tree to another.  What is the maximum distance I could run a joist for the bridge without supporting it in the middle?

Comment: Depends on the size of joist, number, grade, specie, weight of decking and rails, width of bridge, as well as design live load, which is normally 60psf but probably overkill for this application. Also how much deflection is tolerable.

Comment: Down voting because there is not enough information to answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Not what you asked about, but: connecting two trees with a rigid support is a bad idea. Trees move with the wind and the weather, and you'll get an enormous amount of stress in your bridge during a storm as the trees sway. It will probably damage your bridge, and perhaps the trees as well. If you really want to connect two trees (or a tree and a house), consider something flexible like a rope bridge. Of course, designing that is it's own set of questions.